# How to create auto email response when the receiver opens the mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, jakarta-ee, gmail

Hi
My boss wants me to create auto email response when the receiver opens the mail. Most of our clients use gmail but they can use any kinds of mail system. How can I create it ?

Thanks

Comment: You've stated your _project_ more or less as a question here, but you haven't discussed any specific problem other than not knowing how to begin (which, well, given the project, who would?). Still, this isn't answerable in its current form.

Comment: I like that this question was closed as 'unanswerable' after I gave an answer which was accepted. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to be the answer your boss wants to hear, but last time I looked into this there's no reliable way of knowing when someone has opened an email you've sent.

Traditionally (to find out email read counts for marketing emails) it's been done by embedding an image in the email and then having the loading of that image from your server trigger some action; you could do this and have the image address point to a script which sends the auto response then returns a single pixel transparent gif (for example), but it's becoming more standard to disable images in emails these days, so that isn't a 100% reliable route.

That said, if the people you send emails to are more likely than not to load non-embedded images, that is one way to achieve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Read Receipts are not available in GMail:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=3ad9e2c7914d3f0e&hl=en

There's not much support for this feature in many email clients. It's a privacy issue.

Comment: >> Thanks for your reply ! Now I guess I'll have to convince my boss to abandon this.